# How to change the position of minimize button in InternalFrame?

Tags: java, jframe, jinternalframe

I created the `JInternalFrame` in `Jframe` window. If minimize button is click, then the component gets located into the lower left of the container. I want it to be lower right of the screen. How I will do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You have to adapt the method `javax.swing.DefaultDesktopManager.getBoundsForIconOf(JInternalFrame f)`.

For this, two solutions:

1. write your own `DesktopManager` and override `getBoundsForIconOf()`
2. `AOP` with a pointcut on this method which adapt the returned rectangle